# How do I go from Stream<ArrayList<Object>>> to ArrayList<Object> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-stream

I have a `Stream<ArrayList<Object>>` and I want to "extract" the `ArrayList` from it and assign it to a variable. How do I do that?

My resulting variable needs to be of type `ArrayList<Object>` so I can iterate over it and do stuff.

Comment: Do you want to add all elements from every `ArrayList` in the stream into a single big `ArrayList`? Do note that you can iterate over stream and do stuff, tell us what are you trying to do.

Comment: Could you provide some small sample data and what you need as the result?

Comment: check this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-arraylist-from-stream-in-java-8/

Comment: And provide your attempt(s). We are not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get one `ArrayList` then use

```
ArrayList<Object> result = strm.flatMap(ArrayList::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.flatMap` method lets you replace each value of a stream with
another stream and then concatenates all the generated streams into a single stream.

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> collect = Stream.of(objectList)
                .flatMap(m -> m.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```